# How to convert plain text to html in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have freemarker template as below .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Blog</title>
</head>
<body>

<#if username??>
Welcome ${username} <a href="/logout">Logout</a> | <a href="/newpost">New Post</a>

<p>
</#if>

<h1>My Blog</h1>

<#list myposts as post>
<h2><a href="/post/${post["permalink"]}">${post["title"]}</a></h2>
Posted ${post["date"]?datetime} <i>By ${post["author"]}</i><br>
Comments:
<#if post["comments"]??>
    <#assign numComments = post["comments"]?size>
        <#else>
            <#assign numComments = 0>
</#if>

<a href="/post/${post["permalink"]}">${numComments}</a>
<hr>

${post["body"]!""}
<p>

<p>
    <em>Filed Under</em>:
    <#if post["tags"]??>
        <#list post["tags"] as tag>
            <a href="/tag/${tag}">${tag}</a>
        </#list>
    </#if>

<p>
</#list>
</body>
</html>
```

Where   ${post["body"]!""} represents body of my blog and display.

My question : How to represent body tag as html content.

Example : if body has table string

```
<TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0" SUMMARY=""> ... " ,
```

then blog also represent same.

How to convert this string to html table.`enter code here`

Note: body may also have anything (dynamic) and body is not fixed one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you have that table in `body`, then `${body}` will just show the table, if you aren't using template-wide `#escape`. In fact it's recommended to use a template-wide `#escape`, in which case you write `<#noescape>${body}</#escape>`. Where's the problem exactly?

Comment: Hi ddekany.. Thanks for your response... body is not displaying as table format ,it displaying as string "<TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0" SUMMARY=""> ... "

Comment: So then you have to investigate if where does it get escaped. I don't see `#escape` in the template, so check if it's already escaped in the data-model.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. In the controller it got escaped. My issue is   resolved.  Thanks!